# Increase size of file using outputstream

Tags: java

```
String getfileload(){

    char[] fileload= new char fileload[500000]; //500000 is the size file

    for (i=0, i<fileload.length, i++){
        fileload[i]=(random.******) // every random character will be insert in each of the array
    }

    return new String(fileload); // to send back the content of the file load

}
```

Using the above codes, I would like to know, how to increase `500000` of size file to `100MB` or `1GB`. I tried to increase until `1000000000` in the `fileload[]` array ie; `fileload[1000000000]`,  but the error shows:

> 1000000000 is out of int limit.

I was thinking to use `outputstream` but I also need to send back the content of the file load

```
String getFileload(){

String fos = null;
ouputstream newfile = new outputstream(tofile(fos))

for (i=0, i<10000000000, i++){ //1000000000 is size for 1GB *example*
write.fos(65)
}
close.fos()

return fos;
}
```